Jekyll Pagination Not Working (Local Host)
I'm working a very basic website with minimal theme on local host. I want to add pagination but no matter what I did, I can't make working properly. After tried to add pagination, all of my blog posts gone from the home page too.
Here are my files with including pagination codings.

_config.yml

# in the templates via {{ site.myvariable }}.

title: Your awesome title
email: your-email@example.com
description: >- # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  Write an awesome description for your new site here. You can edit this
  line in _config.yml. It will appear in your document head meta (for
  Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description.
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
twitter_username: jekyllrb
github_username:  jekyll

# Paginate
paginate: 5
paginate_path: "/page:num/"


# Build settings
theme: minima

plugins:
  - jekyll-feed

# Exclude from processing.
# The following items will not be processed, by default.
# Any item listed under the `exclude:` key here will be automatically added to
# the internal "default list".
#
# Excluded items can be processed by explicitly listing the directories or
# their entries' file path in the `include:` list.
#
# exclude:
#   - .sass-cache/
#   - .jekyll-cache/
#   - gemfiles/
#   - Gemfile
#   - Gemfile.lock
#   - node_modules/
#   - vendor/bundle/
#   - vendor/cache/
#   - vendor/gems/
#   - vendor/ruby/


index.md

layout: default
title: Home Page
---

<h1>Latest News</h1>

<!-- This loops through the paginated posts -->
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
<div class="post">
    <a href="{{ post.url }}" class="post-thumbnail-link">
        <div class="post-image" style="background-image: url('{{ post.image }}');"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="post-info">
        <span class="post-date"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> {{ post.date | date: "%d.%m.%Y" }}</span>
        <h2 class="post-title"><a href="{{ post.url }}" class="post-link">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="post-excerpt">{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}

<!-- Pagination links -->
<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path }}" class="previous">Previous</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="previous">Previous</span>
  {% endif %}
  <span class="page_number">
    Page: {{ paginator.page }} of {{ paginator.total_pages }}
  </span>
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path }}" class="next">Next</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="next">Next</span>
  {% endif %}
</div>



Gemfile

gem "jekyll-paginate"

Before asking for help, I searched and tried so many ways to fix it but as you can see, I'm here.  I even tried alternative ways to like removing paginate_path, adding gem: jekyll-paginate to _config.yml file and many ways.
